# How to handle responsive design in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, responsive

I am using react native expo and trying to make a app. But as the window size increase my each view get distorted i am using

```
marginTop:'33%'
```

but as i am expanding browser in right hand size then all my views starts going down. How can i manage responsive ness
I have also tried

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

//Guideline sizes are based on standard ~5" screen mobile device
const guidelineBaseWidth = 390;
const guidelineBaseHeight = 844;
const screenSize = Math.sqrt(width * height) / 100;


const scale = size => (width / guidelineBaseWidth) * size;
const verticalScale = size => (height / guidelineBaseHeight) * size;
const moderateScale = (size, factor = 0.5) =>
size + (scale(size) - size) * factor;


export { scale, verticalScale, moderateScale, screenSize };
```

In this i am using moderateScale but not getting any good benefit from it. So please check and let me how can i make apps to show on web as well as mobile size.